# Bracket balancing

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, balanced-string

You will be given a (possibly empty) string containing brackets (`[{()}]`) and any other characters (`A`-`Z`, `a`-`z`, `0`-`9`, punctuation). You need to check if it adheres to the following rules:

- Non-bracket characters are ignored.
- Every open bracket `[{(` has a closing bracket `)}]`. So `[](` is not allowed.
- Brackets are nested properly. `[(])` is not allowed.
- Curly brackets cannot contain square brackets within them. Simple brackets cannot contain either curly or square brackets within them. So `[({})]`, `[{[]}]` and `({})` are not allowed. Brackets can be nested with similar brackets, so `[[{((()))}{{(())}}]()]{()}` is allowed.

Output is a single truthy/falsey value as per your choice.

**Shortest code wins.**

---

**Test cases**

`b[[a{(/)}(())+={{}-}],]` -> Valid

`([h][e][l][l][o])` -> Invalid

`[///[{(\/(arg()))}1{{((-)-2)}}]()]{()}` -> Valid

`hi` -> Valid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fix unbalanced brackets](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11917/fix-unbalanced-brackets)

Comment: @FUZxxl That looks like a much harder challenge. I feel like there is another dupe somewhere though.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes, it can. I've added some testcases. And did you find the duplicate you were looking for?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code No, but I haven't kept searching. Although I think if there is one that checks multiple bracket types it doesn't give them different priorities, so I think this should be fine.

Comment: @MartinBüttner: [This challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21562/fun-with-matching-braces) might be what you were thinking of.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thanks, but I don't think I've ever seen that one.

Comment: I think we should close the other question as a duplicate of this; this is better because it has fewer bonuses.

Comment: @ThomasKwa Please see this link. http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7653/duplicates-of-each-other-wrt-bracket-balancing

Answer (score 5):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 84 bytes

```
^([^][}{)(]|()\(|(?<-2>)\)|(?!\2)((){|(?<-4>)}|(?!\4)(()\[|(?<-6>)])))*$(?!\2|\4|\6)
```

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=bWBeKFteXVt9eykoXG5dfCgpXCh8KD88LTI-KVwpfCg_IVwyKSgoKXt8KD88LTQ-KX18KD8hXDQpKCgpXFt8KD88LTY-KV0pKSkqJCg_IVwyfFw0fFw2KQp2YWxpZAptYF4oPyF2YWxpZCkuKgppbnZhbGlk&input=W1t7KCgoKSkpfXt7KCgpKX19XSgpXXsoKX0KW3soKX1dCmJbW2F7KC8pfSgoKSkrPXt7fS19XSxdClsvLy9beyhcLyhhcmcoKSkpfTF7eygoLSktMil9fV0oKV17KCl9CmhpCgpbKF0pCihbKV0KWyh7fSldClt7W119XQooe30pCihbaF1bZV1bbF1bbF1bb10p)

This is a fairly straight-forward (but golfed) extension [of the basic parentheses-checking .NET regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003799/what-are-regular-expression-balancing-groups/17004406#17004406).

While this is quite possible with balancing groups, [Perl's recursion definitely has the edge here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65569/8478). However, either approach is beaten by ditching the elegance of a single regex match in favour of reducing the input gradually via repeated substitutions, [as Digital Trauma's sed answer does](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65567/8478). This can be implemented in 34 bytes in Retina, but I'm hesitant to post the code myself, as I didn't come up with the idea.

Answer (score 5):

## Retina, 34

Firstly, credit where credit is due:

- @ןnɟuɐɯɹɐןoɯ who [first posted this approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65545/11259).
- @MartinBüttner who [suggested this exact answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65526/bracket-balancing#comment158702_65567) but was too good of a sportsman not to post it himself.

I independently (later) came up with [the same approach in sed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65567/11259), so I hope I'm not treading on any toes ([big](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5828/the-many-memes-of-ppcg/5844#5844) or otherwise) by posting this:

```
[^][(){}]

+`\(\)

+`{}

+`\[]

^$
```

So now with a `sudo apt-get install mono-complete` and `git clone https://github.com/mbuettner/retina.git` I have a working retina on my Ubuntu VM.  Here's the test output:

```
$ while read; do echo "Input: \"$REPLY\", Ouput: $( mono Retina.exe -s brbal.ret <<< "$REPLY" )" ; done < ../brbal.txt 
Input: "[[{((()))}{{(())}}]()]{()}", Ouput: 1
Input: "b[[a{(/)}(())+={{}-}],]", Ouput: 1
Input: "[///[{(/(arg()))}1{{((-)-2)}}]()]{()}", Ouput: 1
Input: "hi", Ouput: 1
Input: "", Ouput: 1
Input: "", Ouput: 1
Input: "([h][e][l][l][o])", Ouput: 0
Input: "[](", Ouput: 0
Input: "[(])", Ouput: 0
Input: "[({})]", Ouput: 0
Input: "[{[]}]", Ouput: 0
Input: "({})", Ouput: 0
$
```

Comment: @ThomasKwa See the test output.  I believe the code is correct and all testcases are passing.  Was there a particular problem you see in the code, or particular testcase you think will fail?

Comment: @ThomasKwa I didn't port their code, because I have no clue what any piece of ESMIN does. I just wrote this code based on what it *looked like* it would do, so I don't think there's any reason this should have the same bug.

Comment: Wow, @MartinBüttner, you got it right! Yeah, I thought that recursively replacing matching brackets inside-out was most logical. A quick tweak to fit the code specs made it work.

Answer (score 3):

## , 43 chars / 62 bytes

```
!Մ(Մ(Մ(ïċ/⁅⬮[\]{}]⌿),`⬮`,⬯),`{}`,⬯),`[]`,⬯)
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=false&input=%28[h][e][l][l][o]%29&code=!%D5%84%28%D5%84%28%D5%84%28%C3%AF%C4%8B%2F%E2%81%85%E2%AC%AE[%5C]%7B%7D]%E2%8C%BF%29%2C%60%E2%AC%AE%60%2C%E2%AC%AF%29%2C%60%7B%7D%60%2C%E2%AC%AF%29%2C%60[]%60%2C%E2%AC%AF%29)</kbd>

Nope.

---

However, if I use newly implemented features, I can get down to 28 chars / 47 bytes:

```
!ïċ/⁅⬮[\]{}]⌿)ė`⬮”ė`{}”ė`[]”
```

Comment: Ohhh, are you removing the matching parentheses from inside out? That would be a mere 34 bytes in Retina: http://pastebin.com/bU77LzbR

Answer (score 3):

## Sed, 53

```
s/[^][(){}]//g
:;s/()//;t
:b;s/{}//;tb
:c;s/\[\]//;tc
```

Here I am claiming that since `sed` does not really have a concept of truthy/falsey, then I am defining the empty string to mean truthy and all other strings to mean falsey.

If that is not acceptable, then we can add a couple of lines, thus:

## Sed, 66

```
s/[^][(){}]//g
:;s/()//;t
:b;s/{}//;tb
:c;s/\[\]//;tc
/./c0
/^$/c1
```

This outputs 0 for false and 1 for true.

Comment: See my comment on molarmanful's answer for the Retina version of the exact same solution (at 34 bytes; printing `0` or `1`). I can't say who should post it, but it should probably be one of the two of you.

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, <s>27</s> 26 bytes

```
"(){}[]"q1$f&_,@2/e*{/s}/!
```

This prints **1** (truthy) or **0** (falsy). [Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=Iigpe31bXSJxMSRmJl8sQDIvZSp7L3N9LyE&input=W1t7KCgoKSkpfXt7KCgpKX19XSgpXXsoKX0) or [verify all test cases.](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cU4vewogICIoKXt9W10iUTEkZiZfLEAyL2Uqey9zfS8hCk59ZlE&input=W1t7KCgoKSkpfXt7KCgpKX19XSgpXXsoKX0KW3soKX1dCmJbW2F7KC8pfSgoKSkrPXt7fS19XSxdClsvLy9beyhcLyhhcmcoKSkpfTF7eygoLSktMil9fV0oKV17KCl9CmhpCgpbKF0pCihbKV0KWyh7fSldClt7W119XQooe30pCihbaF1bZV1bbF1bbF1bb10p)

#### How it works

```
"(){}[]"                    Push that string.
        q                   Read all input and push it on the stack.
         1$                 Copy the bracket string.
           f&               Intersect each input character with the bracket string.
                            This pushes an array of singleton and empty strings.
             _,             Get the length of the array (L), i.e., the number of
                            characters in the original input.
               @            Rotate the bracket string on top of the stack.
                2/          Split it into ["()" "{}" "[]"].
                  e*        Repeat each character pair L times.
                    {  }/   For each character pair.
                     /      Split the string on the stack at occurrences of that
                            character pair. This dosn't work properly the first
                            time, since there's a string array on the stack.
                      s     Flatten the resulting array of strings.
                         !  Apply logical NOT.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), <s>42</s> 37 bytes

*Saved 5 bytes with a feature I didn't realize my own language had... Thanks for adding it, @Downgoat!*

Japt really needs better RegExp support...

```
!Uo"()[\\]\{}" e"\\(\\)" e"\{}" e"\\[]
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=IVVvIigpW1xcXVx7fSIgZSJcXChcXCkiIGUiXHt9IiBlIlxcW10=&input=ImJbW2F7KC8pfSgoKSkrPXt7fS19XSxdIg==)

#### How it works

```
               // Implicit: U = input string
Uo"()[\\]\{}"  // Remove all non-bracket.
e"\\(\\)"      // Recursively remove all pairs of simple brackets.
e"\{}"         // Recursively remove all pairs of curly brackets.
e"\\[]         // Recursively remove all pairs of square brackets.
!              // Return the Boolean NOT of the result.
               // (true for empty string, false for anything else)
               // Implicit: output last expression
```

Answer (score 2):

## C99, <s>226</s> <s>208</s> 207 Bytes

This is my first time ever trying to golf something

```
#define S s[i]
t(s,i)char*s;{int a[]={['[']=0,['{']=0,['(']=0};for(i=0;S*!(S=='{'&a['(']|S=='['&(a['(']|a['{'])|S==']'&(a['(']|a['{'])|S=='}'&a['(']);i++)a[S]++,a[S-S/90-1]--;return !(a['[']+a['{']+a['(']);}
```

Readable:

```
int t(char* s){
    int a[265]={['[']=0,['{']=0,['(']=0};
    for(int i=0;s[i]&&!((s[i]=='{'&a['(']>0)|(s[i]=='['&(a['(']>0|a['{']>0))|(s[i]==']'&(a['(']>0|a['{']>0))|(s[i]=='}'&a['(']>0));i++){
        a[s[i]]++;
        a[s[i]-(s[i]/90+1)]--;
    }
    return !(a['[']+a['{']+a['(']);
}
```

There is a buffer overflow but it doesnt seem to affect anything - I believe this is due to alignment.

Comment: You can omit the space in `char* s`

Comment: Didn't know that - thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>196</s> <s>170</s> <s>160</s> 154 bytes

Awkwardly long, thanks to Mego for saving 6 bytes:

```
d=y=""
for C in input():
 for a in "[](){}":y+=C*(C==a)
 y=y.replace("()",d)
x=y
for r in y:x=x.replace("{}",d)
for s in y:x=x.replace("[]",d)
print(x==d)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 50 + 1 = 51 bytes

```
$_=/^((([^][)(}{]|\((?3)*\))|{(?2)*})|\[(?1)*])*$/
```

Requires the `-p` flag and prints `1` for truthy and nothing for falsy results. I'm counting `-p` as one, because it can be combined with `-e`:

```
> perl -pe '$_=/^((([^][)(}{]|\((?3)*\))|{(?2)*})|\[(?1)*])*$/'
```

The code is basically just a plain regex match against the input, using Perl's nifty recursive regex feature.

Thanks to Dennis for helping me test this and golf the Perl boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 : 120 bytes

Building on [@Adnan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65539/32047), re proved shorter to use:

```
import re
x=re.sub('[^[\](){}]','',input())  
for i in('()','{}','[]'):  
 while x.find(i)>=0:x=x.replace(i,'')  
print(x=='')
```