# A simple number system

Tags: code-golf, number, balanced-string

Let me tell you about a simple number system. <sup><sub><sup>(which I made up just for this challenge)</sup></sub></sup>

This system contains the functions `()`, `[]`, `{}`, and `<>`.

### 1. `()`

When `()` is given no arguments, it evaluates to `0`.

When `()` is given one or more arguments, it evaluates to the sum of the arguments.

### 2. `[]`

When `[]` is given no arguments, it evaluates to `-1`.

When `[]` is given one or more arguments, it evaluates to the first argument minus the sum of the other arguments.

## 3. `{}`

When `{}` is given no arguments, it evaluates to `1`.

When `{}` is given one or more arguments, it evaluates to the product of those arguments.

## 4. `<>`

When `<>` is given no arguments, it evaluates to `1`.

When `<>` is given one or more arguments, it evaluates to the first argument integer divided by the product of the other arguments.

### Your task

Given a string that contains a valid number (that means brackets are balanced, no division by 0s, etc.) in this simple number system, print its value.

### Test cases

```
() -> 0
(()()) -> 0
([][]) -> -2
({}<>) -> 2
({}[]) -> 0
[] -> -1
[[][]] -> 0
[()<>] -> -1
{()} -> 0
{([]<>)} -> 0
```

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the fewest bytes wins.

Comment: I have a great name for this, which I totally just made up and did not get from anywhere else: Brain-flake!

Comment: @ETHproductions no

Comment: [Sort of related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/79625/31716)

Comment: Is division float division or integer division?

Comment: @xnor Integer division

Comment: @Oliver How should integer division work when one or both of the operands are negative? What are the 4 expected results for `5/3`, `5/-3`, `-5/3` and `-5/-3`?

Comment: @Oliver Must the result be an integer on its own, or can it be wrapped in a list/array/1-tuple?

Comment: Uhm ... can I use float division please? The type of division doesn´t really matter for the challenge imo. And it doesn´t make a difference for the given test cases.

Comment: @Oliver @Martin_Ender If you don't want to specify division for negative operands (a bit late now), you might at least demand consistency, such that `<a b c ...>` must be the same as `<a {b c ...}>`. (With the definition of `<>`, that is kind of obvious.) An interesting case is `<{}([][])[]>` vs `<{}{([][])[]}>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 94 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

`o←{(⊂(1⊃⍵),⍺⍺⊃⍵),2↓⍵}⋄u←{(⊃⍵,⍺⍺1)⍺⍺⍵⍵/1↓⍵}⋄⍎⍕'+/o' '-u+o' '×/o' '÷u×o' '(⊂⍬),'[')]}>'⍳⌽⍞],'⊂⍬'`

uses `⎕IO←0`

replaces `)]}>` with a function call that takes a stack, applies an operation on its top frame, deletes it, and appends
the result to its next frame (monadic operator `o` is used for that; dyadic operator `u` handles the more complicated
cases of `-` and `÷`)

replaces `([{<` with code that adds a frame to the stack (`(⊂⍬),`)

executes the resulting expression (reversed, to match APL's order of execution) with an initial stack of one empty frame (`⊂⍬`)

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, <s>357</s> <s>306</s> <s>277</s> <s>251</s> <s>228</s> <s>224</s> <s>188</s> <s>185</s> 180 bytes

A token-based parser with an explicit stack. `(%)` takes a token stack and a character and either pushes (opcode,defaultnumber) or (0,number) for `({[<`, or pops topmost numbers and one opcode and pushes the answer for `)}]>`. Opcodes are encoded by a ascii enumeration hack.

Kudos to @ChristianSievers for his great [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100819/60340) that I borrowed some ideas from.

One-liner!

```haskell
s%c|elem c"([<{",g<-div(fromEnum c)25=(g,[0,0,1,-1,1]!!g):s|(a,(o,n):b)<-span((==0).fst)s=(0,[foldr1(flip$[(+),quot,(-),(*)]!!(o-1))$snd<$>a,n]!!(0^length a)):b
snd.head.foldl(%)[]
```

Now with less error-handling!
Usage:

```haskell
*Main> map (snd.head.foldl(%)[]) ["()","(()())","([][])","({}<>)","({}[])","[]","[[][]]","[()<>]","{()}","{([]<>)}"]
[0,0,-2,2,0,-1,0,-1,0,0]
```

Thanks @ChristianSievers for saving 14+3 bytes!

Thanks @Zgarb for saving some+4 bytes!

Comment: How about `(0,[0,0,1,-1,1]!!o):s` in the fifth line?

Comment: @ChristianSievers of course!

Comment: Switch the definitions of `!`, so you can do `(s:_)!_=d s` as the second case. Also, I think you could bind `x<-p$d<$>init a,y<-d$last a` in the last case of `%`.

Comment: @Zgarb thanks! I found a way to unify the evaluation even more.

Comment: On the third line of `%` you can drop parens around `_:b` and `g c`.

Comment: @Zgarb Oh, didn't have any idea the first one would work

Comment: Oh, you're coming close! I think you can save 3 bytes if you remove `.reverse` and compensate by changing `foldl1(` by `foldr1(flip$`

Comment: @ChristianSievers of course, flipping everything! My mistake was to try to flip only `quot` and `(-)`.

Answer (score 3):

## [PEG.js (ES6)](http://pegjs.org/online), 132 bytes

```
x=a:[([{<]b:x*[)\]}>]{var x='([<'.indexOf(a)
b.length^1||b.push(0)
return~~eval(b.length?b.join(('+-/'[x]||'*')+' '):~-('10'[x]||2))}
```

Should be fixed now.

## Explanation

More readable:

```
x=a:[([{<]
  b:x*
  [)\]}>]
{
  var x='([<'.indexOf(a)
  b.length^1||b.push(0)
  return ~~eval(
    b.length?
      b.join(('+-/'[x]||'*')+' ')
    :~-('10'[x]||2))
  )
}
```

PEG.js is an extended version of Javascript specifically made for parsing. It's VERY strict, which is why I had to use `var`. In addition, there seems to be a bug with brackets inside strings, which bloated the code significantly.

To start, we define a rule `x` that matches any bracket `a` that may or may not contain multiple expressions that matches rule `x`.

For each match to rule `x`, we push a 0 to the array of the inner match `b` if `b`'s length is 1.

If `b`'s length > 0, then we find the index of `a` in `([<` and get a character from `+-/` using that index. If the result is undefined (meaning that `a` was `{`), then we turn the result into `*`. Finally, we tack on a space and join `b` with the result.

If `b`'s length = 0, then we find the index of `a` in `([<` and get a character from `10` using that index. If the result is undefined (meaning that `a` was `{` or `<`), then we turn the result into 2. Finally, we simply decrement.

At the end, we can just evaluate the expression and floor the result.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>292</s> <s>265</s> <s>248</s> <s>235</s> <s>223</s> <s>206</s> 204 bytes

```py
r=reduce
s=input()
for n in')]}>':s=s.replace(n,'),')
for a in'(*x:sum(x)','[a=-1,*x:a-sum(x)','{*x:r(int.__mul__,x,1)','<a=1,*x:r(int.__div__,x,a)':s=s.replace(a[0],'(lambda %s)('%a[1:])
print eval(s)[0]
```

Replaces all brackets with a lambda that does what the bracket does, then evaluates the resulting Python code. Requires its input surrounded by quotes, like `'[<><>([]{})]'`.

This program stores the type of bracket as the first character in each string in the `for`, and everything after the keyword `lambda` as the rest. It then uses the first character to substitute; the rest of it is combined into a lambda like `(lambda*x:sum(x))()`.

[Try it on Ideone!](http://ideone.com/7tilTl)

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 113 + 2 = 115 bytes

Run with `-lp` (2 byte penalty).

```
/\W/,eval"sub $`\{\$#_?(shift)$&&$'1}"for qw'a+a:1- b-a:- c*c: d/c:';y/([{</a-d/;s/\W/0),/g;s/\pL\K/(/g;$_=eval
```

More readable (note: this "more readable version" won't actually run, because I put comments in places they aren't syntactically allowed):

```
              # -p option: read a line of input into $_ at program start
              # -l option: remove the final newline whenever reading
do {          # for each element of a list, given later:
  /\W/;       # place an initial identifier in $`, the next character in
              # $&, and the rest of the element in $'
  eval qq{    # then evaluate the following template, with substitutions:
    sub $` {  # define a subroutine named $`, that does this:
      \$#_ ?  # if there is more than one argument                   
      (shift) # then return the first argument $&-ed with
      $& &$'  # the result of a recursive call with the tail of the arguments
              # else (the "else" is a colon taken from $', not the template)
      1       # return (the remainder of $' applied to) 1
    }
  }
} for qw'     # specify the list by splitting the following on whitespace:        
  a+a:1-      # a(head,tail) = len(tail>1) ? head+a(tail) : 1-1
  b-a:-       # b(head,tail) = len(tail>1) ? head-a(tail) : -1
  c*c:        # c(head,tail) = len(tail>1) ? head*c(tail) : 1
  d/c:        # d(head,tail) = len(tail>1) ? head/c(tail) : 1
';
y/([{</a-d/;  # replace ( [ { < with a b c d in $_
s/\W/0),/g;   # replace whitespace, punctuation in $_ with the string "0),"
s/\pL\K/(/g;  # place a ( after (\K) each letter (\pL) in $_
$_=eval       # evaluate $_ as a Perl program, storing the result back in $_
              # -p option: print $_ to the user at program end
              # -l option: output a newline whenever printing
```

The basic idea is that we're converting an input like `[()<>]` to the Perl program `b(a(0),d(0),0),` via text processing; Perl's just fine with the trailing comma. Earlier, we defined the functions `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` to have the same effect as the `()`, `[]`, `{}`, `<>` constructs from the language we're implementing; they each disregard their last argument (the 0 at the end), which is included to ensure that all input parses correctly, and work using the implementation commonly seen in functional programming where the head and tail are processed separately. Because `b(e,f,g,0)` means `e-f-g`, i.e. treats its first argument specially, whereas `a` treats its arguments symmetrically (`a(e,f,g,0)` means `e+f+g`), we implement `a` recursively and `b` via calling `a`. `c` and `d` have a similar relationship. All four of these functions are very similar, so we generate them at runtime rather than implementing them separately; we store a template that applies to all four functions in a string, then generate the functions by substituting characters into the template.

Because Perl `/` does floating-point division, the implemented `{}` does too. I'm assuming that either this is not a problem in its own right, or `-Minteger` (selecting a language variant where all arithmetic operations are integer operations) is free, because otherwise I'd have to spend extra bytes writing an integer division in Perl, which doesn't seem to be what the problem is fundamentally about. (I think you'd have to spend four bytes changing `(shift)` to `int+(shift)`; I haven't tested this.)

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, <s>215</s> <s>206</s>  198 bytes

```
S='sum(x(:))-sum(x(2:end))';Y='(@(x)isempty(x)';c=']) ';[~,~,u]=unique(['()<>[]{}',input('')]);eval([{'sum([',c,[Y,'+fix((',S,')/prod(x(2:end))))(['],c,[Y,'*-1+',S,'*2)(['],c,'prod([',c}{u(9:end)}])
```

[try it online](http://rextester.com/FTYGI10819)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>315</s> <s>300</s> <s>285</s> <s>258</s> <s>250</s> 244 bytes

```
for($s=$argv[1];$r=!$r;)foreach(["(+)1","[-]0","{*}2","</>2]as$p)if(preg_match("#$e$p[0]([-_\d]*)$e$p[2]#",$s,$m)){if(""==$v=strtok($m[1],_))$v=$p[3]-1;while(""<$n=strtok(_))eval("\$v$p[1]=$n;");$s=strtr($s,[$m[$r=0]=>_.$v]);}echo substr($s,1);
```

replaces sub-expressions with underscore+value;
loop breaks when iteration made no replacement.

19 years since I first met C, 17 years working with PHP;
this is the first time that `strtok` makes sense ... helping to save 24 bytes!

**breakdown**

```
for($s=$argv[1];    // take input from argument
    $r=!$r;)        // toggle $r; loop until no replacement has taken place
    foreach(["(+)1","[-]0","{*}2","</>2]as$p) // loop through operations
        if(preg_match("#$e$p[0]([-_\d]*)$e$p[2]#",$s,$m))   // find a match
        {
            if(""==$v=strtok($m[1],_))  // init $v with first token from sub-match
                $v=$p[3]-1;             // if no token, init with default value
            while(""<$n=strtok(_))      // loop through tokens
                eval("\$v$p[1]=$n;");       // operate
            $s=strtr($s,[$m[$r=0]=>_.$v]);  // reset $r; replace match with underscore+value
        }
echo substr($s,1);  // print result
```

Answer (score 2):

## ES6 (Javascript), <del>250</del>, <del>171</del>, <del>154</del>, <del>149</del>, 147 bytes

A pure Javascript version.

"Metaprogramming" (like most other answers here), converts input program text into a corresponding Javascript program, by applying a number of direct text substitutions to it (i.e. keeping the program structure as is).

Can probably be golfed further.

*UPDATE (v2.1)*

- Minus two bytes (removed parenthesis in the ternary expression)
- Golfed 5 more bytes off, by using variable for result extraction, and getting rid of extra "[]"

*UPDATE (v2)*

Just realised that pending commas in ES arrays are totally valid,
so the whole comma normalization code could be removed.
Also followed an excellent advice by @Titus, on optimizing the alphabet lookup.

*UPDATE (v1)*

Removed duplicate "replace" alias.

*UPDATE (v1)*

- Use a better alphabet: ()=>1+ []=>0 {}=>2* <>=>2/ (each char can be directly re-used as a value or operator)
- Replaced reduce() with replace() (alphabet mapping)
- Merged constant inlining, open and closing bracket processing into one step

**Golfed (v2.1)**

```
s=>eval("o="+s.replace(/./g,r=>"2+1-3*3/"["()[]{}<>".indexOf(r)]).replace(/\d\D?|\D/g,r=>r[1]?r[0]-2+",":r*1?'([':`].reduce((r,a)=>r${r}a)),`)+"o
```

**Golfed (v1)**

```
(s,A="(2)+[1]-{3}*<3>/")=>eval(s[R="replace"](/./g,r=>A[A.indexOf(r)+1])[R](/\d\D?|\D/g,r=>r[1]?r[0]-2+",":(r[0]*1?'([':`].reduce((r,a)=>r${r}a)),`))[R](/,(\])|,$/g,"$1"))
```

**Golfed (v0)**

```
([...s],A="(a)b[c]d{e}f<g>h",R="replace")=>eval(s.reduce((r,c)=>r+=A[A.indexOf(c)+1],'')[R](/ab|cd|ef|gh/g,r=>({d:-1,b:'0'}[r[1]]||1) + ',')[R](/[aceg]/g,"([")[R](/[bdfh]/g,r=>`].reduce((r,a)=>r${"+*-/"["bfdh".indexOf(r)]}a)),`)[R](/,(\])|,$/g,"$1"))
```

**Explained (v0)**

```
//BEGIN 

//s - input text, A - alphabet, R - "String.replace()" alias
E=([...s],A="(a)b[c]d{e}f<g>h",R="replace")=>eval(

//Replace input alphabet by a more friendly one, to avoid too much escaping and quoting
// () - ab, [] -cd, {} - ef, <> - gh
s.reduce((r,c)=>r+=A[A.indexOf(c)+1],'')

//Replace no-arg invocations with a corresponding constant value
// () => 0, [] => -1, {} => 1, <> => 1      
[R](/ab|cd|ef|gh/g,r=>({d:-1,b:'0'}[r[1]]||1) + ',')

//Replace opening brackets with "(["
[R](/[aceg]/g,"([")

//Replace closing brackets with "].reduce(...)),"
//An arithmetic operation to apply (+-*/) is chosen based on the bracket type 
//and is substituted into the template 
[R](/[bdfh]/g,r=>`].reduce((r,a)=>r${"+*-/"["bfdh".indexOf(r)]}a)),`)

//Strip excessive commas
[R](/,(\])|,$/g,"$1")
);

//END: eval() the result


Example:
E("{([]<>()<>{})(<><>)}")
=> eval("([([-1,1,0,1,1].reduce((r,a)=>r+a)),([1,1].reduce((r,a)=>r+a))].reduce((r,a)=>r*a))")
=> 4
```

**Test**

```
E=([...s],A="(a)b[c]d{e}f<g>h",R="replace")=>eval(s.reduce((r,c)=>r+=A[A.indexOf(c)+1],'')[R](/ab|cd|ef|gh/g,r=>({d:-1,b:'0'}[r[1]]||1) + ',')[R](/[aceg]/g,"([")[R](/[bdfh]/g,r=>`].reduce((r,a)=>r${"+*-/"["bfdh".indexOf(r)]}a)),`)[R](/,(\])|,$/g,"$1"))

T=(s,a)=>{
    console.log(s,r=E(s),r==a?"OK":"NOT OK");
}

T("()",0)
T("(()())",0) 
T("([][])",-2)
T("({}<>)",2) 
T("({}[])",0) 
T("[]",-1)
T("[[][]]",0) 
T("[()<>]",-1) 
T("{()}",0) 
T("{([]<>)}",0)
```

**Test Output**

```
() 0 OK
(()()) 0 OK
([][]) -2 OK
({}<>) 2 OK
({}[]) 0 OK
[] -1 OK
[[][]] 0 OK
[()<>] -1 OK
{()} 0 OK
{([]<>)} 0 OK
```

Comment: Could your v0 version go with `s.reduce((r,c)=>r+="abcdefgh"["()[]{}<>".indexOf(c)],'')` (-5)? if so, you could remember `indexOf` in a variable and take the operator from a third string literal.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>184 179 172 161 160 159 151 148</s> 145 bytes

```
s%(c:i)|elem c")}]>"=([1?(*),sum,1?quot,(-1)?(-)]!!mod(fromEnum c)5$s,i)|(r,j)<-[]%i=(s++[r])%j
[v]%e=(v,e)
(v?_)[]=v
(_?o)s=foldl1 o s
fst.([]%)
```

Recursive descent, threading the input because Haskell. As usual, the last line is not a definition, but states the function that solves the problem. So to test, put the lines except the last one in a file, load it and do something like this:

```
*Main> fst.([]%) $ "{([][][])([][])}"
6
```

Thanks to @Zgarb for inspiration and a lot of detailed hints, and to @Angs for inspiration from his solution and further hints.

It wasn't specified how division should behave with negative integers. Anyway, repeatedly using `div` seems wrong, as it is not the same as using `div` once with the product of the remaining values. Now using `quot`, I get the same results for `<{}([][])[]>`and `<{}{([][])[]}>`.

For nice, almost readable code look at the first version. The intermediate versions contain all kinds of nice and intimidating code and help understand this version.

Comment: I think you can save a couple of bytes by defining `(!)=(,)` and using `!` instead of explicit tuples.

Comment: If you define `m x` and `d x` as `1#x` and `0#x`, you can merge the cases `m[x]` and `d[x]` into one, which I think saves some bytes too.

Comment: @Zgarb Thanks! I nearly missed the last pair, without which the `!` trick doesn't pay out. Your second suggestion is evil, there goes my almost readable code... Clever!

Comment: Heh, I just realized that defining `s%(c:i)=(s?c,i)` and `s?')'=sum s` etc will be much shorter, since you can get rid of the repeated `i`s. ..No wait, that probably won't work because of the `s%(_:i)` case.

Comment: Had the same idea and used a guard with `elem`. Down to 175 bytes, still experimenting.

Comment: Lose the backticks on `elem` and `div`, that should save some more bytes.

Comment: Oh hey, you can merge the first two lines into `s%(c:i)|elem c")}]>"=(g c s,i)|(r,j)<-[]%i=(s++[r])%j` and lose 8 bytes.

Comment: I think you can inline g for a few bytes: `([sum,1?quot,(-1)?(-),1?(*)]!!div(fromEnum c-26)26$s,i)`. Btw, this answer is really goddamn nice.

Comment: And div(fromEnum c-8)34) is one byte better

Comment: @Angs Thanks! I found an even shorter way to get an index. (You could similarly use `mod 6` to get from opening parens to different values between 0 and 4.)

Comment: @ChristianSievers I don't think that'll work since in my answer they are not only the index, but they being not `0` is part of the control logic

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), no `eval`, 156 bytes

```
f=s=>s==(s=s.replace(/(.) ?([- \d]*)[\]})>]/,(_,c,s)=>` `+(s?s.split` `.reduce((l,r)=>c<`<`?l- -r:c<`[`?l/r|0:c<`{`?l-r:l*r):c==`[`?-1:c==`(`?0:1)))?+s:f(s)
```

Explanation: The regexp finds the first unprocessed closing bracket, and matches the (presumably) corresponding opening bracket and any arguments in between. The arguments are split and reduced according to the operation (sadly '(' and '[' are not the optimal pair for `+` and `-`), or if there are no arguments then the appropriate value is calculated (again the matching of characters to values is suboptimal from my point of view). The result is then substituted in with a leading space so as to separate it from other results. The function then calls itself recursively until there are no more changes to make, in which case it returns the resulting value. Example:

```
[()<>]
[ 0<>]
[ 0 1]
 -1
```

Comment: _f("([][])")_ => 0 (instead of 2)

Comment: Some other tests are also failing for me (you can give the test code in my [answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100497/61904) a try), probably due to: f("[]")=>0, as "[]" is a part of every failing test.

Comment: @zeppelin Oops, that was due to some bad golfing. I've reverted to a previous version, but sadly that costs me a couple of bytes.