# Bracket checking

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

Consider a string like:

```
a.push(c.push("a",["ad","bd",2,{"ard",duo}]).pop().replace(2,"tg").enc([3,{2,adf},"atr"],5)
```

Write a program that will verify whether a string is correctly bracketed. A correctly bracketed string can be defined as one in which all brackets are terminated (closed), and the inner brackets are terminated before outer ones. Below are example strings:

**Correctly bracketed:**

- `a.push(a,{b,[c,d]})`

**Incorrectly bracketed:**

- `a.push(a,{b)}`

Your program must be able to deal with the following types of brackets:

- Curly (flower) brackets `{}`
- Square brackets `[]`
- Parantheses `()`

If necessary, the string may contain any of these characters:

- Alphabets, uppercase and lowercase (A-Z, a-z)
- Numerics (0-9)
- Double quotes ("), but not single quotes
- Arithmetic operators (+, -, *, /)
- Dots (.)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in terms of bytes wins. The winning answer will be chosen after 7 days from the time of the post.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/77138/34531) or maybe even a duplicate.

Comment: Well written challenge, unfortunate conclusion.