# Bracket Checker

Tags: code-golf, balanced-string

Given a string of brackets tell the user whether or not the brackets are well matched or not. Brackets include `[]{}()`. For example:

```
() <---- Well Matched
([{}][]) <---- Well Matched

({)} <---- Not Well Matched
({]) <----- Not Well Matched
```

**This is a code-golf challenge so as always the shortest solution wins.**

Comment: Welcome to the site! Nice question, unfortunately we [already have it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77138/are-the-brackets-fully-matched).